# Stub fs.promises.readFile() with sinon

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, chai, sinon, fs

I have this fn in node.js which reads json data from file.

```
async getAllProducts() {
        try {
            return JSON.parse(await fs.promises.readFile("data/products.json"));
        } catch (error) {
            if (error.message === "Unexpected end of JSON input") {
                throw new NoProductsExistError("The File is Empty");
            }
            throw new FileReadingError("Error Reading File");
        }
    }
```

I am trying to stub the method. here is my code so far.

```
const chai = require("chai");
const expect = chai.expect;
const sinon = require("sinon");
const dao = require("./dao");
const fs = require("fs");

describe("getAllProducts", () => {
    it("should return all products", () => {
        sinon
            .stub(fs.promises, "readFile")
            .withArgs("data/products.json")
            .returns(
                JSON.stringify([
                    {
                        productId: 101,
                        productName: "Sony XB450AP Wired Headset"
                    },
                    {
                        productId: 102,
                        productName: "Sony XB950"
                    }
                ])
            );

        expect(dao.getAllProducts()).to.equal([
            {
                productId: 101,
                productName: "Sony XB450AP Wired Headset"
            },
            {
                productId: 102,
                productName: "Sony XB950"
            }
        ]);
    });
});
```

However I get this when I run npm test with mocha configured

```
 1) getAllProducts
       should return all products:
     AssertionError: expected {} to equal [ Array(2) ]
      at Context.<anonymous> (data\dao.spec.js:27:35)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:458:21)
```

Not sure how to resolve this. Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

NM, I figured it out...

Correct Code

```
const chai = require("chai");
const expect = chai.expect;
const sinon = require("sinon");
const dao = require("./dao");
const fs = require("fs");

describe("getAllProducts", () => {
    it("should return all products", *async* () => {
        sinon
            .stub(fs.promises, "readFile")
            .withArgs("data/products.json")
            .returns(
                JSON.stringify([
                    {
                        productId: 101,
                        productName: "Sony XB450AP Wired Headset"
                    },
                    {
                        productId: 102,
                        productName: "Sony XB950"
                    }
                ])
            );

        expect(*await* dao.getAllProducts()).to.*deep*.equal([
            {
                productId: 101,
                productName: "Sony XB450AP Wired Headset"
            },
            {
                productId: 102,
                productName: "Sony XB950"
            }
        ]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can try out this code also.
Your function **getAllProducts()** is an **async** function. so you need to put await before the function.
so the code should be

```
describe("getAllProducts", () => {
it("should return all products", async () => {
let fsStub = sinon
        .stub(fs.promises, "readFile")
        .withArgs("data/products.json")
        .returns(
            JSON.stringify([
                {
                    productId: 101,
                    productName: "Sony XB450AP Wired Headset"
                },
                {
                    productId: 102,
                    productName: "Sony XB950"
                }
            ])
        );
    await dao.getAllProducts();
    expect(fsStub).to.be.equal(JSON.stringify([
                    {
                        productId: 101,
                        productName: "Sony XB450AP Wired Headset"
                    },
                    {
                        productId: 102,
                        productName: "Sony XB950"
                    }
                ]));  
        });

});
```

I think it should work.